# Pushing Unique JQuery Objects to an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm completely new to using Jquery, and I'm trying push unique objects to an array, and if the object is already in the array, it removes them. This is for students to book multiple tutorial classes by clicking on available options, and then submitting the full array with all their selected options.

I've updated my code exactly from what I've written. This code works perfectly if I just use single elements in the array. It cannot evaluate duplicate selected slots if I use objects in the array.

```
   var bookingSlots = [];
   $('.row').on('click','.slots', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    var slotID = $(this).attr('data-slot-id');
    var studentID = $(this).attr('data-student-id');
    var slot = {slotID: slotID, studentID: studentID};
    var found = jQuery.inArray(slot,bookingSlots);

    if(found < 0){
        bookingSlots.push(slot);
    }else{
        bookingSlots.splice(found, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: We'll need to see more of your code, e.g., a [mcve] (ideally using Stack Snippets -- the `<>` toolbar button -- to provide a runnable example right there in the question).

Comment: The code you've quoted would work **if** `object` is not recreated every time (and if you fix the `id = var, id2 = var2` syntax error; those `=` should be `:`). But if you're creating a new object every time, that's the problem; equivalent objects are not `==` (or `===`) to each other, so `inArray` will return -1. E.g., `$.inArray({id:1}, [{id:1}])` is -1.

Comment: What is your array content? Add example to better understanding.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for your comment, yes the object is being created on every single click, inArray is returning -1 each time. Thank you, I didn't know that objects couldn't be evaluated to be equivalent in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> the object is being created on every single click

That's the problem: Equivalent objects are not either `==` or `===` to each other, and `inArray` uses `===` to find the object. For instance, `$.inArray({id:1}, [{id:1}])` returns `-1`:

```js
console.log($.inArray({id:1}, [{id:1}])); // -1
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So you'll want to use something else. On modern browsers, you can use `Array#findIndex` and use a predicate function:

```
var index = array.findIndex(function(e) { return e.id == id && e.id2 == id2; });
```

Example:

```js
var array = [];
run(1, 1); // adds
run(1, 2); // adds
run(1, 1); // removes
console.log(array); // ends up with just the 1,2 object in it

function run(id, id2) {
  // Find the equivalent object if any
  var index = array.findIndex(function(e) { return e.id == id && e.id2 == id2; });
  
  // Found?
  if (index == -1) {
    // No, add one
    array.push({id: id, id2: id2});
  } else {
    // Yes, remove it
    array.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

`Array#findIndex` can be shimmed/polyfilled on older browsers; MDN has a polyfill [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) *(I've also quoted it below, just in case, but I can't imagine MDN disappearing any time soon)*.

---

Side note: It's a bit more concise with ES2015 (aka "ES6") (browsers aren't quite ready for us to use ES2015 in the wild yet, but you can transpile):

```
let index = array.findIndex(e => e.id == id && e.id2 == id2);
```

---

Here's MDN's polyfill as of this writing (25/05/2016):

```
if (!Array.prototype.findIndex) {
  Array.prototype.findIndex = function(predicate) {
    if (this === null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.findIndex called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I suggest that you should take a look on [LINQ JS](https://linqjs.codeplex.com/)

Example:

```
var exObjArr = Enumerable.From(array)
                   .Where(function(x){return x.id1 == object.id1 && x.id2 == object.id2})
                   .ToArray();

if(exObjArr.length == 0){
     //object does not exist
} else{
     //object exists
}
```